# How to upload text on Facebook timeline field using android studio?

Tags: java, android, facebook, kotlin

i am trying to upload  text on Facebook timeline  using my app to Facebook app using share dialogue. Below code work fine to share link but not working on only text field.

```
ShareLinkContent content = new ShareLinkContent.Builder()
    .setContentUrl(Uri.parse("https://developers.facebook.com"))
    .build();
```

Comment: You can only share links, Facebook does not currently provide a way to post plain text to user profiles.

Answer (score 0):

1 Open the Facebook Pages app (or download the Facebook Pages Manager app for Android and iOS if you don’t already have it). 2 Tap the toolbox icon at the far bottom right. 3 Under Sharing Tools, click Scheduled Posts. 4 Tap the post to open it, and click the three dots to reschedule or publish now.

Comment: You appear to have misread the question: this is asking how to do so programmatically, not manually via an app.